# Choosing a NoSQL database for storing events in a CQRS designed application

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, consistency, nosql

I am looking for a good, up to date and "decision helping" explanation on how to choose a NoSQL database engine for storing all the events in a CQRS designed application.

I am currently a newcomer to all things around NoSQL (but learning): please be clear and do not hesitate to explain your point of view in an (almost too much) precise manner. This post may deserve other newcomers like me.

This database will:

- Be able to insert 2 to 10 rows per updates asked by the front view (in my case, updates are frequent). Think of thousand of updates per minute, how would it scale?
- Critically need to be **consistent and failure safe**, since events are the source of truth of the application
- Not need any link between entities (like RDBMS does) except maybe a user ID/GUID (I don't know if it's critical or needed yet)
- Receive events containing 3 to 10 "columns" (a sequence ID, an event name, a datetime, a JSON/binary encoded parameter bag, some context informations..). Without orientating your point of view in a column-oriented type of database, it may be document-oriented if it fits all other requirements
- Be used as a queue or sent to/read from an external AMQP system like RabbitMQ or ZeroMQ (didn't worked that part yet, if you could also argument/explain..) since view projections will be built upon events
- Need some kind of filtering by sequence ID like `SELECT * FROM events WHERE sequence_id > last_sequence_id` for subscribers (or queue systems) to be able to synchronize from a given point

I heard of HBase for CQRS event storing, but maybe MongoDB could fit? Or even Elasticsearch (would not bet on that one..)? I'm also open to RDBMS for consistency and availability.. but what about the partition tolerance part..?

Really I'm lost, I need arguments to make a pertinent choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://geteventstore.com/ is a database designed specifically for event streams.

They take consistency and reliability of the source of truth (your events) very seriously and I use it myself to read/write thousands of events a second.

Comment: Fits my needs perfectly, without any hassle. + it's designed by Greg Young, father of CQRS. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I have a [working, in production implementation](https://github.com/xprt64/cqrs-eventstore-mongodb/blob/master/src/Gica/Cqrs/EventStore/Mongo/MongoEventStore.php) of `MongoDB` as an `Event store`. It is used by a `CQRS` + `Event sourcing` web based `CRM` application.

In order to provide 100% transaction-less but transaction-like guarantee for persisting multiple events in one go (all events or none of them) I use a `MongoDB document` as an `events commit`, with events as `nested documents`. As you know, `MongoDB` has [document level locking](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/).

For concurrency I use optimistic locking, using a `version` property for each `Aggregate steam`. An `Aggregate stream` is identified by the dublet (`Aggregate class` x `Aggregate ID`).

The event store also stores the commits in relative order using a `sequence` on each `commit`, incremented on each commit, protected using optimistic locking.

Each `commit` contains the following:

- aggregateId : string, probably a `GUID`,
- aggregateClass: string,
- version: integer, incremented for each aggregateId x aggregateClass,
- sequence, integer, incremented for each commit,
- createdAt: UTCDateTime,
- authenticatedUserId: string or null,
- events: list of `EventWithMetadata`,

Each `EventWithMetadata` contains the `event class/type` and the payload as string (the serialized version of the actual event).

The `MongoDB` collection has the following indexes:

- `aggregateId`, `aggregateClass`, `version` as `unique`
- `events.eventClass`, `sequence`
- `sequence`
- other indexes for query optimization

These indexes are used to enforce the general event store rules (no events are stored for the same version of an `Aggregate`) and for query optimizations (the client can select *only certain events* - by type - from *all streams*).

You could use sharding by `aggregateId` to scale, if you strip the global ordering of events (the `sequence` property) and you move that responsibility to an `event publisher` but this complicates things as the `event publisher` needs to stay synchronized (even in case of failure!) with the `event store`. I recommend to do it only if you need it.

**Benchmarks for this implementation** (on `Intel I7` with `8GB` of `RAM`):

- total aggregate write time was: 7.99, speed: 12516 events wrote per second
- total aggregate read time was: 1.43, speed: 35036 events read per second
- total read-model read time was: 3.26, speed: 30679 events read per second

I've noticed that `MongoDB` was slow on `counting` the number of events in the event store. I don't know why but I don't care as I don't need this feature.

I recommend using `MongoDB` as an `event store`.

Comment: I do not know MongoDB, but I'm not sure to understand how you did implement a sequence number for commits, given commits are seperate documents? Is the sequence itself a document as well? If so, how did you implement a gap-less sequence? If your sequence is not then, how do you ensure sequences are actually committed in order (e.g cannot read sequence 2 before sequence 1).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, MongoDB is (for the moment) one of my preferred option and your implementation could really help. But what I really need is to compare all options (let's wait for some comparative answer..)

Comment: @plax each commit (so each document) has a property: sequence that is incremented

Comment: @YonnTrimoreau I see, I understand, I'm also curious

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Are you serializing all the writes?

Comment: @plax Unfortunately YES. I know. This will be resolved in future releases. This could be done because the global ordering of events should not be the responsibility of the events store but of the event publisher. The event store has the solely responsibility of persistence of the events. This responsibility will be moved but as I said, for now, it will stay there.

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Ok I understand now, so basically you fetch the previous commit sequence at the start of every transaction and increment it. If 2 commits are made at the same time one fails because of the unique constraint and the transaction starts over effectively serializing writes using optimistic locking. Wouldn't be better to lock pessimisticly here? Concurrency conflicts will happen often if there are lot of writes in the system and you could enter retry loops.

Comment: @plax I try to not use pessimistic locking as it is kind of anti-scaling technique. I know that sometimes optimistic could hurt as well but it's just a felling and I haven't give it too much thought as I plan to move that `sequence` out of the `event store`

Comment: I'm almost done implementing a SQL Server backed store and the way I'm planning to solve this is to have a dedicated single-threaded sequencer that goes over the events and sequence them after they were written. The main downside is that you cannot read the events in global order before they get sequenced, but you can within a stream since writes are serialized within streams.

Comment: @plax But how do you know in which  order they are written?

Answer (score 1):

I have an .NET Core event sourcing implementation project  https://github.com/jacqueskang/EventSourcing

I started with relational database (SQL Server and MySQL) using entity framework core.
Then moved to AWS so I wrote a DynamoDB extension.

My experience is that relational DB can do the job perfectly but it depends on requirement and your technical stack. If your project is cloud based then the best option  might probably be cloud provider's no-sql database like AWS DynamoDB or Azure CosmosDB, which are powerful in proformance and provide additional features (e.g. DynamoDB can trigger a notification or lambda function)